# Photoshop BRUSH : Need a LONG, THIN, rope brush

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

[image: Sample of Brushes that I need to modify]

I am trying to make a rope border on an 8.5 x 11 brochure. I downloaded a free set of ROPE BRUSHES and chose one to accomplish the rope on the top edge of my image which is attached. I did not have to brush on the rope with multiple clicks. It was one long, straight, rope.

I clicked on the image and the 8.5” top border was magically filled with a long thin rope-border.  Next, I clicked on the bottom edge and an identical rope filled the bottom edge.   But, the rope on the bottom edge was partially hidden by a layer on top of it.  So I went out of brushes to work on the layering issue.

When I went back to the brushes, I saw 15+ jpegs. I assumed the jpeg’s were downloaded with the free brush, and I did not know that one could create a brush out of a jpeg, so I thought I was being scammed and deleted all of the jpegs.

I went back to the brushes, but realized that one of the jpegs must have been used to create the rope. I reloaded the brushes and spent 6 hours attempting to recreated my long-thin rope.

I want the rope to be long and thin, but if I increase the 1” identical brush size to 1600 pixels to get the rope long enough, then it becomes enormously wide (2") as shown in the attached image. HELP! I want my rope to be approx 1/4 in x 11".

The 2nd rope in the attached image is exactly the width I need. How do I elongate it without increase the width?

Comment: "As a rookie to this site, please offer suggestions to be a better member." Reading that [tour]  that was suggested when you signed up would have been dandy. It's really short, so nothing to worry about. There is also a [Help] with lots of additional information.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm . . .  It would seem these are just images of a rope, not actual properly made Photoshop brushes.

Instead, better to make your own rope brush preset in Photoshop.  It can be done in a few minutes, not hours.

All you need to begin with is a photo of some rope.  Either take your own photo or find a stock photo.

Use the Pen Tool to make a path around one segment of the rope, and turn the path into a selection, then click *Edit > Define Brush Preset*

[image]

Open the Brush Settings menu (F5)

Under the Brush Tip Shape settings, change the size to make the brush smaller, then set the Spacing to something like 72%. This percentage will differ depending on the actual rope, so you will need to tweak it until you get something that looks like a rope. Obviously the segments should slightly overlap each other.

Then in the Shape Dynamics, change the Angle Control to *Direction*.

[image]

Click the tiny menu icon at the top right of the Brush Settings, and click New Brush Preset, give your Brush Preset a name.

That's it!

Have fun painting ropes!

[image]

To paint a straight line, click once with the brush, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then click another point, and a line will be drawn between the two.

[image]

Change the thickness of the rope by changing the size of the brush

[image]

Comment: I'm a little disappointed you didn't draw a fancy knot in the gif... I'm going to grade this answer `B-`.

Comment: @Joonas LOL, I'll let you into a little secret, it doesn't work so well when it comes to creating a tight knot or curve.  That's why I didn't do it!

Answer (score 3):

Vector graphics programs allow you to use shapes as brushes. If you have a good straight horizontal PNG image with transparent background you can use it as a curve stroke texture. Place it into the brushes collection and draw a line, curve or other shape. The result is a warped raster image which gets rewarped if you edit the shape.

[image]

Random curves are drawn with different stroke colors and widths. This is from Affinity designer. My original prototype PNG is shown in window Rope0.png

The same works in Illustrator. Search for Illustrator raster image Pattern Brush. One example of available tutorials: https://creativepro.com/creating-a-pattern-brush-illustrator-cc-using-a-raster-image/

You can copy and paste the result to Photoshop if needed.

NOTE: the ends of the prototype PNG must be  prepared carefully to fit. Othervise the joints are too obvious in the drawn long ropes. My example is not a masterpiece in this sense. Making the lights and shadows same at both ends should be thought as early as possible, most preferably when taking the photo.

White rope:

Whitening a normal brownish rope isn't easy because in real white rope the dark areas are much narrower. Here's one attempt starting from the same rope photo as the images above. Whitening is done in Photoshop with desaturating and applying curves:

[image]

It isn't especially plausible. It looks more like one has tried to paint a piece of normal rope. Colorizing the stroke to blue in A.Designer affects grey areas (definitely unrealistic, too) but it pulls the attention off from bad painting.

A shadow is added to make separation.

Better result needs a photo of real white rope or more research how to do the whitening properly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a straight line, increasing the brush spacing:

[image]

For the vertical brush set the brush **Shape Dynamics**

- Check **Brush Projection**
- Select **Angle Jitter Control**: **Direction**

[image]